# How could I do this? Refine search results as I type

Tags: jquery, search, live

I've got a page with a bunch of thumbnails and titles:

<strike>http://thenozzle.net/games</strike> 
(broken link)

If you hit "search", a search bar slides down from above. I can type things into the search box and hit enter to search the website. I was wondering if there was any way to look at all the thumbnails, and if I typed "E" it would hide all the thumbnails except for ones that started with "E". Then I typed "El" and it brought up every result that started with "El". Then I added a "d" and it would bring up every thumbnail with a title starting with "Eld". IN this, users could search the games page easily without having to reload. Is it possible? Worthwhile doing?

I've well-versed in jQuery and PHP. If my explanation didn't do it. Look into [Google Instant](http://www.google.com/instant/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made something like this a while ago. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HJQsp/)'s a link.

What it does is fire this event on every key press, and matches the pressed key with a `li` that contains it. It works great, but could definitely use some modification. Here's the code:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("li").hide();
   var term = $(this).val();
    $("li:contains('" + term + "')").show();
});
```

Comment: WHOA that's easier then I though!

Comment: HOWEVER: that just fins it. I need it to START with the letter, reading left -> right.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: It does. Try typing "Bob" with the first "b" capitalized. This is where it needs some refinement. I could spend some time finding a way to match it to a lowercase version of each `li`'s contents.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: OH! Now I see what you mean. Lets's see what I can come up with...

Comment: @JacksonGariety: Could you email me? It's on my profile. We'll continue this through there. :)

Comment: @JacksonGariety: Sorry for the double comment, but I just threw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HJQsp/1/) together and it works wonderfully. You can search with capitals or lowercase and it'll search from left to right.

Comment: :D Trying it out now, looks great!

Comment: Now when I try your code... NOTHING happens when you search. see:
http://thenozzle.net/games

Can you help diagnose? It's in the middle of scripts.js

Comment: Fiddled around with it a bit and found my solution! Thanks!

The issue was that your code was hiding an element with text DIRECTLY inside it and showing an element with text DIRECTLY inside it.

I need to hide and show thumbnails that have text nested in other elements so I did this:

Hide all the thumbnails: $(".child-thumb").hide();

Locate the TEXT element (even if it's nested: $(".thumb-title").each(function(){

Show the PARENT of that text element: $(this).parent(".child-thumb").show();

Comment: ALSO: Can I tell it to ignore apostrophes?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a JS (with jquery) code that performs json calls to retrieve a list of coincidences to the string already typed as it goes. It should show them in a div nearby the input field updating the innerHTML or something like that.

Below, a script/servlet/service that can be called every time with the input.

Example: http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/

Comment: Purmou's was SO MUCH lighter you wouldn't believe it. Thanks for the tut. I'll check this out further it Purmou and I can't come up with something smaller.

Comment: I like the way @Purmou deals with it. Although you need all the thumbnails in the current page for it to work. If your page works that way, have no doubt his approach is your way out (simpler is always better).

If you need to search over a whole bunch of games, check out the tut. Good luck

Comment: If people want to search the whole site.. they hit "enter". If they happen to be on a page that supports this "instant" thing I'm implementing, it will start narrowing down content. I can also do this with posts on the homepage! :D