# Javascript for matching text while typing

Tags: javascript

Basically, i need a code that constantly checks for how many times a particular string appears within a textarea everytime the user keys in a letter.

```
  <textarea name="t_update" cols="50" rows="5" id="t_update" style="width:30%"
 onKeyUp="check()" ></textarea>

 <script>
     function check(){
         var cText = document.getElementById('t_update').value;
         if (cText.match("abc")){
             //Do something
         }else{
             //Do something else.
         }
         alert(cText.match("abc").length);
     }
 </script>
```

The current code i have only returns one even if i have a more than one match. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192076/814761) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use match with a regular expression and a global

```
cText.match(/abc/g).length
```

//test

```
cText = "aaabbbbcccabcabchalloabc" 

Firebug Console
cText = "aaabbbbcccabcabchalloabc" cText.match(/abc/g).length
>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use split on your string like this:

```
 function check(){
   var cText = document.getElementById('t_update').value,
   matches = cText.split('abc').length-1;

   if (matches){
    //Do something
   }else{
     //Do something else.
   }
   alert(matches);
 }
```

Comment: split is not that what he wants. lol. and its wrong. if you have "abc" you got ["abc"] (is 1 -1 is 0). ;-)

Comment: @huan son: actually `'abc'.split('abc')` returns `["", ""]` so it works just fine. Regarding what the OP wants I don't quite think you can decide that, but thanks for deeming my answer not useful to make your own look better :s

Comment: oh yeah, i just see that in JS it returns a 2 field array. it doenst bother me if my answer is good or not. if you are searching in strings with split, i only have to say that you are programming with a horribly style. obvious we can make our own function and check each byte on and on, but this is also not the right style. the task is: "check a string for matchings". and now you can ask yourself why there is a function called "match". if the task is "split the string in x parts" then we use the .split() .....cheers xmas